# Can't update layout with referenceBlock

Tags: magento2

I can't update layout using reference Block.
This is my site block: custom.topnav. See screenshot

[image]

This is the code of the Extension Ves Mega Menu

```
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <!--
            /**
             * Venustheme
             * 
             * NOTICE OF LICENSE
             * 
             * This source file is subject to the Venustheme.com license that is
             * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
             * http://www.venustheme.com/license-agreement.html
             * 
             * DISCLAIMER
             * 
             * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
             * version in the future.
             * 
             * @category   Venustheme
             * @package    Ves_Megamenu
             * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2016 Venustheme (http://www.venustheme.com/)
             * @license    http://www.venustheme.com/LICENSE-1.0.html
             */
            -->
            <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
                <head>
                    <css src="Ves_All::lib/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css" />
                    <css src="Ves_All::lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-tiny.css" />
                    <css src="Ves_Megamenu::css/font-awesome.min.css" />
                    <css src="Ves_Megamenu::css/animate.min.css" />
                    <css src="Ves_Megamenu::css/styles.css" />

                    <!-- Enable Off canvas menu css
                    <css src="Ves_Megamenu::css/megamenu-offcanvas.css" />
                -->
                </head>
                <body>
                    <referenceBlock name="custom.topnav">
                        <block class="Ves\Megamenu\Block\Menu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Ves_Megamenu::topmenu.phtml">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">mainmenu</argument>
                            </arguments> 
                        </block>
                    </referenceBlock>
                    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="magemenu.js" template="Ves_Megamenu::js.phtml" />
                    </referenceContainer>
                </body>
            </page>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Is there a problem with the extension? Or are you trying to modify the extension? What have you tried already?

Comment: i am trying to put mega menu template part in the block of my template. the problem is that i can't debug, i am new in magento template xml system. i read the documentations but i can't understand how to debug. the template is not updating.... there's a problem of cache?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Id` tag `htmlId=""` in blocks, why you selected `custom.topnav` id as a block name ? it's not always the case.

`referenceBlock` refer for the block `name`.

You have to check in your **xml** the block name then set that name as a reference, the same think for the containers `referenceContainer` refers to the name and not the id

Exemple:

```
<container name="name.block" label="some block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="some-class" htmlId="name-id">
...
</container>
```

Here in your source code you will see `<div id="name-id"...>` so to refer to this container what to take is the `name` and not the `id`.

To tell you that the **name** and the **id** are still not necessarily the same all the time.

## Update:

I don't know exactly your xml and the block name, I suggest you to follow this solution:

1. Add the code bellow within `<body></body>` in your `xml`:

   ```
   <body>
       ...
       <block class="Ves\Megamenu\Block\Menu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Ves_Megamenu::topmenu.phtml">
       ...
   </boby>
   ```
2. in your div: `<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-5 col-menu"></div>` add within the code bellow :

   ```
   <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('catalog.topnav'); ?>
   ```

Comment: ok i get it. one question. whit all the modules installed, my xml template now is modfied by all those modules. i can't find the right xml to watch. suggesions?

Comment: You want to add a block or set the template block by another one ?

Comment: i have this div: <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-5 col-menu"></div>, i'd like to put Ves Mega Menu inside this, so from what i understand, this: 

<block class="Ves\Megamenu\Block\Menu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Ves_Megamenu::topmenu.phtml">
    <arguments>
     <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">mainmenu</argument>
    </arguments> 
   </block>

Comment: Please look my update